# Xamarin deployment to Android emulator never finishes

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I have an Xamarin Android project. Now I cannot get the app started in the emulator anymore. After building the solution the emulator starts but the app is never deployed.

The output window in Visual Studio shows this:

```
Starting deploy EmulatorName ...  
Starting emulator EmulatorName ...  
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd EmulatorName -prop monodroid.avdname=EmulatorName  
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start  
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off  
Hax is enabled  
Hax ram_size 0x40000000  
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.  
Emulator EmulatorName is running.  
Waiting for emulator to be ready...  
Deploying EmulatorName ...  
Build started.  
...  
Using "AndroidZipAlign" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MS  
  PackagedResources:  
    obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources  
  SDCardDirectory:   
  External: False  
  ManifestTemplate: obj\Debug\android\AndroidManifest.xml  
  EnableInstantRun: False  
  InstantRunForceUploadApk: True  
  AndroidSdkPath: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk  
  AndroidNdkPath: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b  
  JavaSdkPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_112  
  Found AndroidSdk at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk  
  Found AndroidNdk at C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b  
  Found AndroidTools at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools  
DEBUG RunShellCommand emulator-5554 getprop  
TASK: GetProperties getprop completed?:[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xms]: [64m]  
[dalvik.vm.dex2oat-Xmx]: [512m]  
[dalvik.vm.heapsize]: [256m]  
[dalv...
```

Comment: For me, it never starts if the emulator wasn't running. I wait until emulator is open, cancel build, start debugging again - deploys.